# What was the worst economic crisis of all time?

Tags: economy

I am interested in reading about the worst economic crisis of all time. By that I mean the largest reduction in GDP over a period of at least a year. The economic crisis should not have been caused by war nor natural catastrophe, but events that could arise arise in a stable society today, like a financial crisis, economic mismanagement or similar.

Comment: Off topic. How did you arrive at the conclusion that war does not happen in stable society? Usually the exact opposite is true.

Comment: @kubanczyk Thank you for asking me to clarify, what I meant to say was that I am not interested in the economical crisis in Iraq that was caused by the invasion.

Comment: Your assumption that there is such a thing as a "stable" society is dubious, as is your assumption that economic crises are unrelated to "instability."

Comment: How about the repercussions of the Black Death?...

Comment: I understand that the question could be clearer, so please suggest how to clarify it.

Comment: Which of these would you consider worse: a tiny country whose economy completely collapses, leading to the starvation of most of its people; or a worldwide economic crisis where far more wealth is lost, but spread out so that most people don't feel much worse off.

Comment: @joe Excellent question. I would measure it in terms of the amount of wealth lost.

Comment: In Portugal [earthquake in Lisbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1755_Lisbon_earthquake) had devastating effects on the country, but I don't know how it can be compared to other crisises

Comment: Do you want us to include severe famines from ages when most production was agricultural?

Comment: There are crises which happen over a year or a few years -- the Great Depression -- and those that happen over decades or centuries of consistant mis-management.  They are very different and you should be clearer which you mean.  Secondly, do you want an absolute fall in the economy of a particular nation or area or is a relative fall compared with other countries (which could come from them growing)?  The question really needs clarity!

Comment: I'm surprised that no one mentioned what happened in Britain after the fall of Rome. The economy basically went to zero in short order (as evidenced by currency circulation, which disappeared for all practical intents, and the archeological records of towns in the era, e.g. York disappeared entirely), and things pretty much stayed that way for centuries.

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy Was it fast? The impression I have is that it was a slow process with the landowners abandoning the towns for country villas even before the legions left and the return to impoverished rural life being over a century or more, just as in Europe.

Comment: @MarkOlson: Best I recollect it went quite quickly. One generation was actively participating in the Roman trade economy. The next one was scattered across the countryside with only subsistence farming left to do. Which by the standards of the time that was rather quick. And then one needs to wait until around the 10th century or so for the economy to pick back up. Anyway, it probably isn't the type of answer OP is looking for, but I felt like putting it out there for the curious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Economist illustrated the [History of World GDP](http://www.ritholtz.com/blog/2010/08/history-of-world-gdp/) by way of the intriguing graphic below.

[image]

The mismanagement of the Chinese Qing empire between the years of 1820 and 1913 is plain to see. Similarly, assuming that [colonialism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonialism) satisfies the OP's criteria, the difference in percentage GDP of (British) India between 1700 and 1940 is simply astounding.

Comment: But the chart shows percentages - so when you're using it to argue about, say, the impact of Colonialism on India, you are ignoring the Industrial Revolution...

Comment: Btw, where is Russia/SU on the graph?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Presumably somewhere above the 70% marker. I don't know why it isn't featured in the graph. Good point on the industrial revolution.

Comment: I wish this graph had Egypt, SW Asia, and Mexico

Comment: While this is certainly interesting information, it does virtually nothing to answer the question posed.  Not only is the data percentages -- so that the grown of some other country looks like shrinking of the rest -- but it's not even per capita data. A country with rising population can grown i percentage of the world GDP while the people in it slip into poverty.

Comment: The Soviet Union's economy was worth over $2T in 1985 and was second only to the US in size.

Comment: Most of the drop in China's share of the world GDP isn't from Qing mismanagement, it's from the incredible industrial boom in the United States.

Comment: @MarkOlson's point is dead on. The most important point being that changes in global percentage do not track well changes in GDPR. Nor can we tell what is due to "mismanagement" and which to "war" etc. This should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

Up front, imho GDP and "like a year" is not really suited for objective comparing of historic economic crises, which run on time scales of at least several years or a decade, smaller time scales are better called economic fluctuations. Comparing economic crises in different historical epochs, national and world-wide ones, by proportional (%) GDP reduction might turn out a bit tricky, due to incomplete data and different assessment basis.

But anyway, regarding economical, poltical mismanagment or faulty construction of economic system by pure better-known numbers, the **biggest economic crisis was the [Great Depression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Depression)**

> In previous depressions, such as those of the 1870s and 1890s, real per capita gross domestic product (GDP)—the sum of all goods and services produced, weighted by market prices and adjusted for inflation—had returned to its original level within five years. In the Great Depression, real per capita GDP was still below its 1929 level a decade later.
>
> Economic activity began to decline in the summer of 1929, and by 1933 real **GDP fell more than 25 percent**, erasing all of the economic growth of the previous quarter century. Industrial production was especially hard hit, falling some 50 percent. By comparison, industrial production had fallen 7 percent in the 1870s and 13 percent in the 1890s.
>
> **In the absence of government statistics, scholars have had to estimate unemployment rates for the 1930s.** The sharp drop in GDP and the anecdotal evidence of millions of people standing in soup lines or wandering the land as hoboes suggest that these rates were unusually high. It is widely accepted that the unemployment rate peaked above 25 percent in 1933 and remained above 14 percent into the 1940s. Yet these figures may underestimate the true hardship of the times: those who became too discouraged to seek work would not have been counted as unemployed. Likewise, those who moved from the cities to the countryside in order to feed their families would not have been counted. Even those who had jobs tended to see their hours of work fall: the average work week, 47 to 49 hours in the 1920s, fell to 41.7 hours in 1934 and stayed between 42 and 45 until 1942.
>
> (Source: Encyclopedia Britannica)

Austrian economist Kurt Richebacher states in a [economic analysis of the Great Depression](http://www.gold-eagle.com/editorials_00/richebacher051000.html) (the whole article is worth reading):

> This view about the ultimate cause of the Great Depression predominated among economists around the world until the early 1960s. But one book, appearing in 1963, radically changed that view, at least among American economists. It was Friedman's and Schwartz's classic, Monetary History of the United States. This book categorically postulated that there had been neither inflation nor any money or credit excesses in the 1920s that could have caused the economy's collapse between 1929 and 1933. **From this followed the conclusion that the Great Depression essentially had its crucial cause in policy faults that were made during these years.**
>
> To quote a decisive passage from the book, "The monetary collapse from 1929 to 1933 was not an inevitable consequence of what had gone before. It was the result of the policies followed during those years. **As already noted, alternative policies that could have halted the monetary debacle were available throughout those years.** Though the Reserve System proclaimed that it was following an easy-money policy, in fact it followed an exceedingly tight policy."

---

"Smaller/national" examples in 20th century would be:

- Japanese asset price bubble, 1986-1990
- Argentine inflation in the 80s & 90s

For crises before 20th century a look on these examples might be interesting:

- Tulip Mania in Netherlands, 1637
- Collapse of Easter Island Civilization (still a active research field in economics concerning ecological economics, sustainability and *Malthusian catastrophe*)
- Collapse of Maya Civilization, again a non-sustainable managing of natural resources is ONE of the theories trying to explain its decline

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question to make it, "at least a year" instead of something like a year. I wrote it to avoid answers referring to short-term crashes. One question, though, how do you know that the Great Depression was the biggest economic crisis?

Comment: @David more or less common knowledge, I heared it many times in documentations, but read the first sentence in linked analysis of renown economist Richebacher for a objective statement and comparison with todays economy. Also, as said, you cannot fully compare Great Depression with e.g. todays financial bubbles in a globalized economy or national Japanese bubble in the 80s or Easter Island. Makes more sense to analyse those crises within the given context. Great Depression lasted for one decade, industrial production fell by 50%! Easter Island was a total collapse. What was worse? ;)

Comment: You could likely add Zimbabwe and Russia

Comment: @DVK I would think that Zimbabwe would beat the great depression easily, but I do not know this.

Comment: @David - I don't have any data on their GDP. But they did have this minor problem of hyperinflation, which - even if GDP didn't contract - would have a significantly WORSE effect on anyone living there who doesn't have access to non-Zimbabwe currency assets.

Comment: @David:  Depends on what you're looking for.  The Great Depression affected most of the world's largest economies, while the Zimbabwe hyperinflation affected one very small economy.  I'm sure I can find major disasters that hit very small economies if I look for them.

Answer (score 4):

The Great Depression of 1929-1933 showed a fall in real GDP in the United States of 38.1% according to [this source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_recessions_in_the_United_States). This was probably the greatest fall in real GDP in the independent history of the US, although the Panics of 1796 and 1819 could have been larger.

Beyond the US, Britain's biggest recession was the 25% fall following the end of the First World War, which exceeded the 5.8% fall experienced there in the Great Depression.

Some areas of the former Soviet Union [experienced a 45% fall](http://www.citymayors.com/society/easteurope_cities.html) in GDP after the transition from planned and globally integrated economies to isolated and market oriented economies.

Going further back, the [Great Depression of the 14th century](http://mises.org/daily/3861/) in Europe led to a fall of up to 40% in some countries.

Answer (score 2):

One of the hardest was possibly the crisis in Russia due to introduction of Capitalism, the breakup of the USSR in 1991 and pro-American policy of the Yeltsin's government.

This is the drop of GDP per captia:

[image]

This is graphic depicting the drop in industrial output in Russian Federation (blue) and Moscow (red), in per cents to the level of 1991:

[image]

This graphic shows index of machinery production of Russia, in percents to the level of 1991:

[image]

This graphic shows the GDP per captia of Russia (blue) and the constituents of the USSR (red) in 1950-2010 conpared to that of the USA in the same year (in purshasing parity prices).

[image]